# How do I send progress of S3 upload in aws-amplify (React native)?

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I am able to upload an image to S3 and send the progress to the console but unable to set the state of a component. It seems like the progress cant be sent to an external function. Even if I have a function that logs it to console, the function does not get called.

```
Storage.put(text, Buffer.from(photo.base64, "base64"), {
  progressCallback(progress) {
    prog = parseInt(progress.loaded/progress.total*100)
    console.log(prog+"%");
    this.setState({uploadProgress: prog+"%"})
  },
  contentType: "image/jpeg"
})
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're calling `this` in the callback of the Storage.put method. You can cache the reference to `this` outside of the Storage.put method like (for lack of a better term) this:

```
const foo = this;
Storage.put(text, Buffer.from(photo.base64, "base64"), {
  progressCallback(progress) {
    prog = parseInt(progress.loaded/progress.total*100)
    console.log(prog+"%");
    foo.setState({uploadProgress: prog+"%"})
  },
  contentType: "image/jpeg"
})
```

Comment: THANK YOU! After a day of trying all sorts of dereferencing/passing this was the one that worked...